# Chapter number, right margin, using report

Tags: titlesec, report

I have a thesis template I created during my studies. And for my master thesis, I want to add some "neat looking" design to it.

I'm going for figures in the margin, as well as side nodes. Simply accomplished with the `geometry` package. However, for my chapter styles, I am at a loss.

I would like my numbers to appear in the right margin (solved, using the `titlesec` package). I want the text of the chapter and the number to be separated by a rule of some sort. Basically, I would like something like this:

[image]

I am confident this style is created by using the `\documentclass{scr(something)} Koma script` I believe. I have never used this, and a bit "scared" to switch from my old comfy template to that.

I have come up with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[includemp,
paperwidth=20.90cm,
paperheight=29.7cm,
top=2.170cm,
bottom=2.510cm,
inner=2.1835cm,
outer=2.1835cm,
marginparwidth=4cm,
marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newlength\mylen
\addtolength{\mylen}{\linewidth+70pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape}
    {\makebox[0pt]{\makebox[\linewidth+\mylen][r]{\scalebox{2}{\vrule\itshape\thechapter}}}}{0pt}{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction which has a way to long title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Yielding

[image]

Is there anything I can do, in report document class. To come closer to the aforementioned output, or do I need to consider switching class?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some box juggling:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % if you want to use Computer Modern
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  twoside,
  openright,
]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  includemp,
  a4paper,
  top=2.170cm,
  bottom=2.510cm,
  inner=2.1835cm,
  outer=2.1835cm,
  heightrounded,
  marginparwidth=4cm,
  marginparsep=0.4cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\skovmandchapternumber}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{\textwidth}\hspace*{1em}%
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\fontsize{40}{0}\itshape\thechapter}%
  }%
}
\newsavebox\skovmandchapterbox
\newcommand{\skovmandchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \sbox\skovmandchapterbox{%
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\parbox[b]{0.8\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}%
  }%
  \hfill\usebox{\skovmandchapterbox}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
    \ifdim\ht\skovmandchapterbox<15pt
      \vrule height 15pt depth 15pt width 1pt
    \else
      \vrule height \dimexpr\ht\skovmandchapterbox + 3pt\relax
             depth  \dimexpr\dp\skovmandchapterbox + 6pt\relax
             width 1pt
    \fi
  }%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\scshape}
  {\skovmandchapternumber}
  {0pt}
  {\skovmandchaptertitle}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chapter which has a way too long title}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The `fix-cm` package is not needed if your document uses a freely scalable font. The idea is that the rule covers at least the number, but if the title gets longer, the rule extends a bit above and below it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A beautiful solution to my problem. Really appreciated! So glad this was doable!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works, thanks to the `explicit` option of `titlesec` and the use of a `tabularx`. I added some colour (personal taste) but it's easy to remove. Also, don't forget to define `\titleformat` for unnumbered chapters (e.g. bibliography), as part of this code is meaningless for them.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper, openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[includemp,
paperwidth=20.90cm,
paperheight=29.7cm,
top=2.170cm,
bottom=2.510cm,
inner=2.1835cm,
outer=2.1835cm,
marginparwidth=4cm,
marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newlength\mylen
\addtolength{\mylen}{\linewidth+70pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filleft\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\rlap{\makebox[\mylen][r]{\scalebox{2}{\color{LightSlateGray!40}\itshape\thechapter}}}}{0pt}
{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth + \marginparsep}{@{}>{\raggedleft}X!{\,\color{LightSlateGray!40}\vrule width 3pt}}#1\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction which has a way to long title}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I chose the answer given by @egreg, even though your answer does the trick as well. But I preferred the varying rule.
You made me remember to fix the unnumbered style though!